# How to resize a partition to its maximum capacity after partitioning it to half of its capacity?

Tags: linux, command-line, mount, partition

After cloning a 1TB hdd "TO" a 2TB hdd, in which the 2TB hdd is now only 1TB... The following format will not allow me to resize it properly, to its max capacity. Seems as though it won't get resized to a bigger size than it is now.

**FORMAT USED:**

```
parted
resizepart
partition #
size 2000000MB (OR) 2GB
```

"sectors exceed msdos parition max..." It says that it 'exceeds' the max by almost 1GB.

**UPDATE**: after repartitioning it at a slightly larger size than it was, I can no longer mount it.

Comment: You can use gparted. Make sure the disk is unmounted.

Comment: Your question seems to have muddled up GB and TB. For example 2000000 MB is 2 TB but you describe it as 2 GB. At this point I'm no longer sure which parts of your question really mean GB (if any) and which means TB

Comment: The mention of "msdos" tickles me. What's the partition type? FAT32 have a maximum size of 2 TB (however I suppose that doesn't matter, if your disk is "2 TB", it's likely something like "2,000,000,000,000 B", while the actual FAT32 limit should be around 2^41 bits, so 2,199,023,255,552 B. Give it a look anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Resize disk partition to max disk size with `cfdisk`: (you are targeting device)

```
cfdisk /dev/xyz
```

Choose: `Resize` (max size should be default), `Write`, `Quit`.
You can check changes with `lsblk`.

Now you have to resize the file system to match partition size: (you are targeting a partition)

```
resize2fs /dev/sdXY
```

You can check how it went with `df -h`.

---

If you are resizing a virtual disk (VMWare, ESXi, VirtualBox) and you don't want to restart the machine to see disk size changes, just scan the disk you resized: (you are targeting device)

```
echo 1 > /sys/class/block/sdX/device/rescan
```

Now you can resize the partition and file system, like I described in this post.

Answer (score 0):

Cloning is just was it say a clone (identical copy) of the cloned.

To change the size you have to **resize** the partition on the cloned disk with a tool ex. parted.

Ref.: https://www.tecmint.com/parted-command-to-create-resize-rescue-linux-disk-partitions/

Comment: Matsk. Thanks. I will read the link. So, I can resize it then without deleting the data. With making a new partition, I have to delete everything I think.

Comment: For some reason it is not allowing me to fully resize. In the article that person used MB's to resize. I am trying with both GB and MB but it won't let me; telling me I am over the max. Seems like it will only go as large as the current size of the partition.

Comment: Create and Boot up Ubuntu from a USB stick and start gparted. Gparted is a graphical version of parted. It could be that you need to install gparted on the USB stick.